# Быстрая сортировка двумерного массива по возрастанию простых чисел

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка, матрицы, простые-числа

```
class QuickSortPrime {
public static int[][] sortMatrixPrime(int [][] matrix, byte rows, byte cols) {
    int temp[] = new  int[rows*cols];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            temp[k++] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    qsort(temp, 0,temp.length-1);
    k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = temp[k++];
    return matrix;
}
public static void outputMatrix(int [][] matrix) {
    for (int x[]: matrix) {
        for (int y: x) {
            System.out.print(y + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
private static boolean isPrime(int[] items) {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i] > 1 & items[i] < 4) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int j = 4; j <= items[i] / j; j++) {
            if ((items[i] % j) == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
private static void qsort(int[] items, int left, int right) {
    int i, j;
    int x, y;
    if(isPrime(items)) {
        i = left;
        j = right;
        x = items[(left + right) / 2];
        do {
            while ((items[i] < x) && (i < right)) i++;
            while ((x < items[j]) && (j > left)) j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                y = items[i];
                items[i] = items[j];
                items[j] = y;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        while (i <= j);

        if (left < j) {
            qsort(items, left, j);
        }
        if (i < right) {
            qsort(items, i, right);
        }
    }
}
}

public class MyMatrix {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Random r = new Random();
    byte rows = Byte.parseByte(reader.readLine());
    byte cols = Byte.parseByte(reader.readLine());
    int[][] matrix = new int[rows][cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = r.nextInt(100 + 100 + 1) - 100;
        }
    }
    QuickSortPrime.outputMatrix(matrix);
    QuickSortPrime.sortMatrixPrime(matrix, rows, cols);
    System.out.println("================");
    QuickSortPrime.outputMatrix(matrix);
}
}
```

Задача: Отсортировать матрицу по возрастанию простых чисел (т.е. дан двумерный целочисленный массив в диапазоне от [-100, 100], состоящий из rows - строк и cols - столбцов, нужно по возрастанию отсортировать в этом двумерном массиве ТОЛЬКО простые числа НЕ затрагивая другие (они остаются на своих местах)).

Проблема: Программа сортирует не так как надо.Так как не могу грамотно интегрировать в алгоритм сортировки проверку на простоту числа.

Входные данные:

```
1 -3  7 33 -34 21
6  4  5 21  66 11
0 43  2 90  61 17
```

Ожидаемые данные:

```
1 -3  2 33 -34 21
6  4  5 21  66 7
0 11 17 90  43 61
```

Comment: В чём суть задачи?

Comment: Что такое сортировка матрицы? Это неоднозначное понятие. Что означает "по возрастанию простых чисел" ?

Comment: приведите пример входных и ожидаемых выходных данных

Comment: ничего не понимаю, вы 2 просто забыли переставить или это какая-то странная схема сортировки? если я правильно понимаю идею, матрица при сортировке рассматривается просто как массив написаный в несколько строк

Comment: В каком смысле "2"?

Comment: число 2, оно же простое. 3 строка 3 столбец

Comment: Да, ошибся, сейчас переделаю, спасибо, что подметили

Comment: Вариантов на самом деле много, можно например сформировать отдельный массив(или даже матрицу) из имеющихся простых чисел и сортировать его, к примеру храня вместе с каждым числом его позицию

Comment: Уже пытался так сделать, но увы, не осилил, может завтра получится

Answer (score 0):

> Проверка на **простое число:**

**[Простое число](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE)** — натуральное (целое положительное) число, имеющее ровно два различных натуральных делителя — единицу и самого себя. Другими словами, число x является простым, если оно больше 1 и при этом делится без остатка только на 1 и на x. К примеру, 5 — простое число, а 6 является составным числом, так как, помимо 1 и 6, также делится на 2 и на 3.

```
private boolean checkIfPrimeNumber(int number) {
    if (number < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(number);
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Я знаю как ищется простое число, но в моём случае данный метод и мой аналогичный не решает поставленной задачи, т.к. он не адаптирован под мой случаи и скорее всего не правильно интегрирован в алгоритм быстрой сортировки.

Comment: В цикле достаточно перебрать числа, не превосходящие корня из проверяемого числа.

Comment: Отрицательные простые не обрабатываются.

Answer (score 0):

Следует запомнить индексы ячеек, содержащих простые числа, в какой-то коллекции, сами простые числа сохранить в сортированном множестве `SortedSet` или приоритетной очереди `PriorityQueue` и в конце переписать элементы в матрице, используя известные индексы и вычитывая элементы в нужном порядке.

При этом индекс ячейки можно представить в виде одного числа, а не пары "строка -- столбец".

```java
public static void sortPrimes(int[][] matrix) {
    Set<Integer> indexes = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue();
    int rows = matrix.length;
    int cols = matrix[0].length;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            int x = matrix[i][j];
            if (isPrime(x)) {               // для простых чисел
                indexes.add(i * cols + j);  //   сохраняем индекс ячейки
                pq.add(x);                  //   и значение
            }
        }
    }

    for (int ix : indexes) {      // для индексов ячеек с простыми числами
        int r = ix / cols;        //    вычисляем номер строки
        int c = ix % cols;        //    и колонки
        matrix[r][c] = pq.poll(); // и переписываем нужное значение
    }
}
```

Для обнаружения простых чисел в матрице имеет смысл воспользоваться [оптимизированным алгоритмом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1463949/386633) с запоминанием.

Оптимизации:

- Отбрасываются числа, кратные 2 и 3
- Проверяются числа, меньшие или равные квадратному корню из искомого `n`
- Применяется формула `6m ± 1`, генерирующая ряд `5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25...`
- Проверяются только *натуральные* числа, большие 1 (отрицательные числа и 0 не являются простыми)

```java
private static Set<Integer> primes = new HashSet<>(Set.of(2, 3));

public static boolean isPrime(int n) {    
    if (primes.contains(n)) {  // нашли известное простое число
        return true;
    }
    boolean prime = n > 1 && (n % 2 != 0) && (n % 3 != 0);
    
    for (int i = 5, d = 2; prime && i * i <= n && i * i > 0; i += d, d = 6 - d) {
        prime = n % i != 0;
    }
    if (prime) {
        primes.add(n);
    }
    
    return prime;
}
```

---

Вспомогательный метод для генерации матрицы заданного размера, содержащей случайные числа в заданном диапазоне (с использованием Stream API, в частности метода для генерации случайных чисел [`Random::ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-)):

```java
private static int[][] randomMatrix(int rows, int cols, int min, int max) {
    Random r = new Random();
    return IntStream.range(0, rows)
        .mapToObj(i -> r.ints(cols, min, max).toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```

Вспомогательный метод для вывода только простых чисел в матрице (остальные заменяются точками для улучшенной наглядности):

```java
private static void printPrimeMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    for (int[] r : matrix) {
        for (int n : r) {
            if (isPrime(n)) {
                System.out.print(n);
            } else {
                System.out.print(" . ");
            }
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

Тест:

```java
int[][] m = randomMatrix(4, 8, -100, 100);
printPrimeMatrix(m);
System.out.println("---------");
sortPrimes(m);
printPrimeMatrix(m);
```

Вариант вывода:

```
 .  41   .   .  61   .   .  53  
37   .   .   .   .   .  17  31  
 .   .   .   .   .  97   .  37  
 .   .   .   .   .  29   .   .  
---------
 .  17   .   .  29   .   .  31  
37   .   .   .   .   .  37  41  
 .   .   .   .   .  53   .  61  
 .   .   .   .   .  97   .   .
```