# Необходимо создать и заполнить двумерный массив парами простых чисел

Tags: java, массивы, простые-числа

Необходимо, чтобы программа заполняла массив парами простых чисел `matrix` и возвращала его тестовой среде в виде `int[amount][2]`

```java
public class PrimeTwins {
    public static int[][] primeTwins(int amount) {

        int[][] matrix = new int[amount][2];

        System.out.printf("(%d,%d)\n",3,5);
        for(int n = 1, k = 1; n < amount; ++k)
        {
            if (primeNumberCheck(6*k-1)&&primeNumberCheck(6*k+1))
            {
                System.out.printf("(%d,%d)\n",6*k-1,6*k+1);
                matrix = new int[6*k-1][6*k+1];
                ++n;

            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }

    private static boolean primeNumberCheck(int n){
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){
            if (n % i == 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------//
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the amount");
        int amount = scn.nextInt();
        int primeprime[][] = primeTwins(amount);
    }
}
```

Я пытался сформировать двухмерный массив с `amount` строчек и двумя столбцами, но мне не хватает знаний как это сделать. Не нашёл как это сделать в интернете.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140369/discussion-on-question-by-bogdan-klinowitzki-----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, для проверки является ли число простым следует отбросить чётные числа/кратные 3 и проверять числа меньшие, чем корень из n:

```java
private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    // полное условие
    // boolean prime = n > 1 && (n %2 != 0 || n == 2) && (n % 3 != 0 || n == 3);
    // сокращенная форма, так как входные значения n >= 5
    boolean prime = n %2 != 0 && n % 3 != 0;
    for (int i = 5, d = 2; prime && i * i <= n && i * i > 0; i += d, d = 6 - d) {
        prime = n % i != 0;
    }
    return prime;
}
```

Во-вторых, для записи пар простых чисел в строку двумерного массива следует записывать меньшее число по индексу 0, а большее - по индексу 1:

```java
private static int[][] primeTwins(int amount) {
    // резервируем место под amount пар
    int[][] m = new int[amount][2];
        
    for(int n = 0, k = 5; n < amount; k += 6) {
        if (isPrime(k) && isPrime(k + 2)) {
            System.out.printf("(%d, %d)\n", k, k + 2);
            m[n][0] = k;
            m[n][1] = k + 2;
            ++n;
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Тест:

```java
int[][] m = primeTwins(10);
        
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(m));
```

Вывод:

```
(5, 7)
(11, 13)
(17, 19)
(29, 31)
(41, 43)
(59, 61)
(71, 73)
(101, 103)
(107, 109)
(137, 139)
[[5, 7], [11, 13], [17, 19], [29, 31], [41, 43], [59, 61], [71, 73], [101, 103], [107, 109], [137, 139]]
```